# Material-UI and Redux-form not styling when being mapped

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I've created this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/pk8p4lvl90

I can implement the material-ui instructions (https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/examples/material-ui/) fine without the mapping mechanism, but as soon as I apply the mapping I can't get the material-ui to implement the look for a textfield.

In my example I have commented out the code I have tried that works without mapping being involved.

Form -

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <div>
    {/* <Field
      name="firstName"
      component={renderTextField}
      label="First Name"
    />*/}
    <FieldArray
      name="firstName"
      component={renderTextField}
      label="First Name"
    />
  </div>
</form>
```

TextField Render -

```
    const renderTextField = ({ fields, input, label }) => (
      <div>
        {fields.map((newIntel, index) => (
          {/* <TextField 
                name={newIntel} 
                key={index} 
                label={label} 
                placeholder={label} 
                component="input" 
                placeholder={label} 
                label={label} /> */}

          <Field
            name={newIntel}
            key={index}
            label={label}
            placeholder={label}
            component="input"
            placeholder={label}
            label={label}
          />
        ))}

        <div
          variant="fab"
          color="primary"
          className="jr-fab-btn"
          aria-label="add"
          onClick={() => fields.push()}
        >
          Click me
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `redux-form` features with `material-ui` look, you need use `redux-form`'s input component with render function that will return `material-ui`'s component with appropriate props. You started doing so, but `renderTextField` should look a little bit differently, e.g.:

```
const renderTextField = ({
  input,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error },
  ...custom
}) => (
    <TextField
      hintText={label}
      floatingLabelText={label}
      errorText={touched && error}
      {...input}
      {...custom}
    />
  )
```

Having this, you can reuse it in, let's say `renderForm` function:

```
const renderForm = ({ fields, input, label }) => (
  <div>
    {fields.map((newIntel, index) => (
      <Field
        ...
        component={renderTextField}
        ...
      />
    ))}
    ...
  </div>
);
```

That's based on what I've found in the redux-form Docs you linked. Take another look there as well, it's well described there as well.

Comment: Yes thats my issue, I need rendertextfield to map in order to have the button to create another TextField

Comment: And I think that should be enough to resolve that issue :-) Please take a look at the updated https://codesandbox.io/s/0ylv6wnr2w

Comment: Nice one! That's awesome